# Flow type error: "number [1] is incompatible with `Number` [2] in property `index`" - using React context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype, react-context

using React context & I think the reason it might not be working is because of a type issue in Context file. The issue says:

Cannot call `createContext` with object literal bound to `defaultValue` because  number [1] is incompatible with  `Number` [2] in property `index`.Flow(incompatible-call)

```
// @flow
import React, { createContext, useContext } from "react";

export type CountryIndexProviderType = {
  index: Number,
};

const CountryContext = createContext<CountryIndexProviderType>({
  index: 0,
});

type CountryContextProviderProps = {
  index: Number,
};

const CountryContextProvider = ({ index }: CountryContextProviderProps) => {
  return <CountryContext.Provider value={{ index }}></CountryContext.Provider>;
};

const useCountryIndexContext = () => useContext(CountryContext);

export { CountryContext, CountryContextProvider, useCountryIndexContext };
```

COMPONENT 1:

```
import { CountryContextProvider } from "/EnteredCountriesContext";

return (
  <StyledWrappingContainer>
    <StyledProgress>{index + 2}</StyledProgress>
    <CountryContextProvider index={index}></CountryContextProvider>
  </StyledWrappingContainer>
);
```

COMPONENT 2:

```
import { useCountryIndexContext } from "/EnteredCountriesContext";
const { index } = useCountryIndexContext();

<StyledWrappingContainer>
   <StyledProgress>
      <StyledProgress>{index + 2}</StyledProgress>
   </StyledProgress>
</StyledWrappingContainer>
```

Can anyone spot what my issue might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change

```js
index: Number,
```

to be

```js
index: number,
```

A `Number` is an object, `number` is a primitive type.